# How to create sub menu in Drupal 8 using views result for specific item of the menu?

Tags: views, 8

I have one menu link available in the **Main Menu**. It is called as **"Video"**.

In my system, there is vocabulary called as **"Video Taxonomies"**. It have following taxonomies entries.

1. Entertainment
2. Comedy
3. Friction

I have created one block for listing all this category.

Now, I want this block result would appear under "Video" link of the **Main Menu**.

So, I want following output when we will hover on the Video Link of the Main menu.

- Video Link

  - Entertainment
  - Comedy
  - Friction

I have used https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_views for Drupal 7.

Please suggest.

Comment: Menu links are managed with a plugin manager. You can achieve this task by implementing a plugin deriver class for the menu links plugin.

Comment: See https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21menu_link_content%21src%21Plugin%21Deriver%21MenuLinkContentDeriver.php/8.2.x  and https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21menu_link_content%21menu_link_content.links.menu.yml/8.2.x

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Plearse do check the following code. We have used that for creating the sub menu and please let me know if there is proper way.

Answer (score 1):

We have implemented using the

```
MODULE_NAME_menu_links_discovered_alter(&$links).
```

In which, We have accessed the result of the block by using the following code.

```
 $result = views_get_view_result("view_name", "display_id");
    foreach($result as $result) {
      $title = "Entertainment"; // we have took as static
      $tid = 10;
      $slug = str_replace(' ', '_', strtolower($title));
      $links[$slug] = array(
        'title' => $title,
        'route_name' => 'view.VIEW_NAME.DISPLAY_ID'
        'route_parameters' => array('arg_0' => $tid),
        'description' => 'Dynamic',
        'provider' => 'MODULE_NAME',
        'parent' => 'menu_link_content:DATABASE_UUID_OF_SELECTED_CATEGORY',
        'id' => $slug
      );
    }
```

We have used **route_name** for assigning the url, this url should be the existing url of the drupal site.

We need **route_parameters** for passing the arguments.

For accessing the **Video Link : reference** in **parent** of **$links**. I have got it from the

```
SELECT uuid as DATABASE_UUID_OF_SELECTED_CATEGORY FROM `menu_link_content` where id = "TID_Video_Link_of_Main_menu"
```

After that, We have used that id in **parent** as **'menu_link_content:04c479c9-7234-4de2-a4f0-e03b0a3003b6'** so all links will be added below the Video Link of the main menu.

After doing all the code and we need to clear the cache. And we are able to see the sub menu from the views of texonomy to Video Link of the main menu.

Please suggest me if there is any better way than this.

**For Reference:** https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Menu!menu.api.php/function/hook_menu_links_discovered_alter/8.2.x

Comment: Your code would be a lot more maintainable if you used a deriver class instead. But don't worry, it takes some time to get use to writing for drupal 8.